qulacs simulator in QAOA
I am trying to solve an optimization problem with QAOA method but when I run this part:
dev = qml.device("qulacs.simulator", wires=wires)

I got this error:
"DeviceError: Device qulacs.simulator does not exist. Make sure the required plugin is installed."
I tried to update pennylane and this is my qml.about():
Name: PennyLane
Version: 0.36.0
Summary: PennyLane is a cross-platform Python library for quantum computing, quantum machine learning, and quantum chemistry. Train a quantum computer the same way as a neural network.
Home-page: https://github.com/PennyLaneAI/pennylane
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /Users/fatemeghavidel/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: appdirs, autograd, autoray, cachetools, networkx, numpy, pennylane-lightning, requests, rustworkx, scipy, semantic-version, toml, typing-extensions
Required-by: PennyLane-qiskit, PennyLane_Lightning

Platform info:           macOS-13.3-arm64-arm-64bit
Python version:          3.11.4
Numpy version:           1.23.5
Scipy version:           1.10.1
Installed devices:
- default.clifford (PennyLane-0.36.0)
- default.gaussian (PennyLane-0.36.0)
- default.mixed (PennyLane-0.36.0)
- default.qubit (PennyLane-0.36.0)
- default.qubit.autograd (PennyLane-0.36.0)
- default.qubit.jax (PennyLane-0.36.0)
- default.qubit.legacy (PennyLane-0.36.0)
- default.qubit.tf (PennyLane-0.36.0)
- default.qubit.torch (PennyLane-0.36.0)
- default.qutrit (PennyLane-0.36.0)
- default.qutrit.mixed (PennyLane-0.36.0)
- null.qubit (PennyLane-0.36.0)
- lightning.qubit (PennyLane_Lightning-0.36.0)
- qiskit.aer (PennyLane-qiskit-0.35.1)
- qiskit.basicaer (PennyLane-qiskit-0.35.1)
- qiskit.ibmq (PennyLane-qiskit-0.35.1)
- qiskit.ibmq.circuit_runner (PennyLane-qiskit-0.35.1)
- qiskit.ibmq.sampler (PennyLane-qiskit-0.35.1)
- qiskit.remote (PennyLane-qiskit-0.35.1)


I tried this code which worked:
pip install qulacs pennylane-qulacs

